# Flat ConstraintLayout with layout_constraintHeight_min for each row doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have what I think is a pretty common use case: I have multiple rows of information on the screen. I'm hoping to implement these views without having to use nested ViewGroups. Each row should have a minimum height, but expand if the contents are larger than the minimum height. The contents should be nested vertically.

It seems like this simplified example should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#8800ff00"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Instead of creating a ViewGroup for each row, I have a flat layout with constraints. A View for each row sets the row height and can be clickable. The views inside the row are siblings in the layout hierarchy, but center themselves vertically in the middle of the View for that row. Since I've specified `app:layout_constraintHeight_min` and anchor the bottom of the View to the bottom of the contents, it should grow with the contents.

But there's a problem:

[image]

ConstraintLayout adds undesired spacing above the row! Note that the unwanted spacing above the row is equal to the correct spacing between the bottom of the contents and the bottom of the row.

My theory is this: since the View's bottom is anchored to the bottom of the contents (the TextView) it wants to stick tightly to that and be right next to it. If I force it to move further away, it adds something like a bottom margin to accomplish that, it adds a similar top margin to be symmetrical.

How do I make it stop? If it wasn't for that unwanted spacing on the top, I'd have exactly what I need. Perhaps there's some special ConstraintLayout trick, some magical attribute to fix this behavior. Or maybe there's a completely different way to use ConstraintLayout to accomplish the UI I want.

I realize that using fixed-height rows would make this much simpler, but I don't like doing that if the contents can grow.

I could change my UI to have a nested ConstraintLayout for each row, but I'd rather not do that after working so hard to make a complex layout completely flat, without multiple layers of ViewGroups. But that's what I'll do if I can't find a better solution, which I hope to find here.

Comment: So basically you want "wrap_content" with min_height.

Comment: The bottom of the text view is constrained to the bottom of the green view, but the bottom of the green view is constrained to the bottom of the text view. This is a circular dependency that is resolving unhappily instead of throwing an error. It looks like you want the green view to appear like a view group. Without the green view, are all the widgets properly placed and the green view is simply a wrapper, or are the widgets dependent upon the placement of the green view? The answer to that question will drive the answer.

Comment: @TheLibrarianCz the ConstraintLayout equivalent of that, yes. But to use `wrap_content` would require additional ViewGroups, which I said I'm trying to avoid. I have tried experimenting with `layout_constraintHeight_default = wrap`, but haven't found a way to make it do what I want. If you have a solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Cheticamp What I have provided is the smallest possible demonstration of the problem. Yes, the green view is necessary. Yes, it's acting like a ViewGroup, but without being a ViewGroup. The green view helps to manage the height of the row and make the entire row area clickable. If there's another way to accomplish the goals I've listed, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: After experimenting and research, I cannot find an answer to this question. I'm giving up and sadly, I'm refactoring my perfectly flat layout into having a nested ConstraintLayout for every row. Perhaps a future release of ConstraintLayout will handle this common use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing  the min height and adding some margin in the TextView will do the thing and **instead of using match_parent you can use constraints if possible**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:text="Row is not column"
        android:textColor="#283858"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#8800ff00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Here is my output]

Comment: Thanks for answering! the problem is that in this case I need to precisely enforce a minimum height--my real world use case is more complicated than this example.

Comment: so i think this occupies some minimum height even though if there is no content